# BibTex not working in Texmaker 3.5.2

Tags: bibtex, texlive, texmaker, windows

I have the following tex-code where I tried using bibtex:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Testing bibtex in Texmaker}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is a test cite:\citep{ab94}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

I'm using `elsarticle-num-names.bst` bibliography style file and my `biblio.bib` is the following:

```
@article{ahu61,
       author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
       title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
       journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
       volume={8},
       year = 1961,
       pages = {175-191}
     }

@book{ab94,
       author = {Charalambos D. Aliprantis and Kim C. Border},
       year = {1994},
       title = {Infinite Dimensional Analysis},
       publisher = {Springer},
       address = {Berlin}
     }

@incollection{m85,
       author={Maskin, Eric S.},
       year={1985},
       title={The theory of implementation in {N}ash equilibrium: a survey},
       booktitle={Social Goals and Social Organization},
       editor={Leonid Hurwicz and David Schmeidler and Hugo Sonnenschein},
       pages={173-204},
       publisher={Cambridge University Press},
       addess={Cambridge}
     }
```

If I run this file in Texmaker I get the error:

[image]

If I remove the `\citep{ab94}` command I get no errors, but the bibliography doesn't appear in the PDF-file, no matter how many times I compile the tex-file.

I'm using Texmaker 3.5.2 and here is my configurations:

[image]

Another very common errors I get (using different tex- and bibtex-file) with bibtex in Texmaker are:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'.
```

and

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> C.~D. Renn\�
o
l.257 \bibinfo{author}{C.~D. Renn\�o}
, \bibinfo{author}{J.~ao~Ricardo~de
```

My operating system is 64-bit Windows 7. Any ideas what is causing my problems...? Why can't I get BibTex working here?

P.S. Please let me know if you need any more details. I will provide if required :)

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{cite}`.  Almost all of its functionalities are provided by `natbib`. Then it should work.

Comment: Hi @HarishKumar I removed the \usepackage{cite} and it compiled now. However in the place of the \citep{ab94} I got a question mark even though I compiled multiple times. I also got two warnings: Citation 'ab94' on page 1 undefined, and: there were undefined citations.

Comment: You have to run bibtex too. Select bibtex from the compile menu and run it. Then again xelatex two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first page of `natbib`s user manual says this:

> It is compatible with the packages: babel, index, citeref,
>   showkeys, chapterbib, hyperref, koma and with the classes amsbook
>   and amsart. It can also emulate the sorting and compressing functions of the cite package as well as the multiple citation (and merg-
>   ing) functions of Thorsten Ohl’s mcite package. (The natbib package, however, is not compatible with either cite or mcite themselves.)

Hence you can't use both `cite` and `natbib` packages. As you can emulate the functionalities of `cite` package with `natbib` itself, remove `\usepackage{cite}` and add the option `sort&compress` to `natbib` package:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
```

You can read more on this in section 2.16, page 18 of `natbib` guide.

To get citations properly, you have to compile the document with `pdflatex` the `bibtex`, again `pdflatex` & `pdflatex`.