# Getting undefined citations even though bib file is in the right folder

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using TexMaker. I produced a bib file with Citavi and saved it in the folder that my tex-file is in. Although i thought i set everything up correctly I get warnings of undefined references, my citations show up as question marks in the text and no reference list is produced.

I checked for typos etc. but couldn't find anything. My bib file also shows up in TexMaker.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I just cannot find it.

Here is the possibly relevant part of my tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepackage{cite}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

example citation: \cite{Stern.2004}

\newpage 

\bibliography{sources}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

And here a snippet of my bib file:

```
@article{Stern.2004,
 author = {Stern, David I.},
 year = {2004},
 title = {The Rise and Fall of the Environmental Kuznets Curve},
 pages = {1419--1439},
 volume = {32},
 number = {8},
 issn = {0305750X},
 journal = {World Development},
 doi = {10.1016/j.worlddev.2004.03.004}
}
```

Comment: have you run bibtex to generate the bibliography?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out because of your comment. Ran latex and bibtex on my tex file in the shell and now it also works in TexMaker.

Comment: I don't know texmaker but you will be able to set up a menu item to run latex bibtex latex if it is not already set up. I would expect that it will be as it is very standard latex processing order

Comment: this answer shows a texmaker configuration with bibtex and other commands set up https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236446/bibtex-not-working-in-texmaker-3-5-2